Generating Carmichael numbers in polynomial time
I'm generating RSA 2048-bit keys with $p$ and $q$ of 1024-bit primes. For primality, I'm using the Miller-Rabin test. As Carmichael numbers pass the MR test, I tried to compute how many such numbers exist.
From wiki, the number of Carmichaels numbers exist are  $C(X)>X^{0.332}$.
So the number of 1024-bit Carmichael numbers are 2339.07.
In relative terms the probability that a chosen prime number is Carmichael number is  2−678.01 which is significantly low.
My doubt is since the amount of Carmichael numbers that exists which is 2339.07 is quite a significant number and if there is a way these numbers are generated in polynomial time there is a high possibility that one can easily install backdoors or purposefully can generate weak RSA keys with Carmichael numbers as primes.
Is there exists any such algorithm that can generate Carmichael numbers in polynomial time? Is there any sort of this kind of insider attack that happened on RSA before, if so can you please share some references?

First note that Carmichael numbers do not pass all MR tests, at least 75% of MR witnesses will identify a Carmichael number as composite. However, for any fixed set of witnesses, it is possible to construct a Carmichael number which the witnesses avow as composite (see Arnault Constructing Carmichael numbers which are strong pseudoprimes to several
bases.
With regard to polynomial time construction of Carmichael numbers, we believe that a simple way to do this is by generating Chernick numbers which are number of the form $(6n+1)(12n+1)(18n+1)$ where all three brackets are prime. A sharper form of Dickson's conjecture tells us to expect that the proportion of $n\le x$ for which all three brackets are prime is $O((\log x)^3$. All Chernick numbers are Carmichael numbers.
Thus by choosing random $n$ performing three polynomial time primality proofs, e.g. the AKS primality test we can find Carmichael numbers in polynomial time.
There are other methods, such as Arnault's, to generate more sophisticated Carmichael numbers with particular pseudo-prime properties and the possibility of using these maliciously has been studied at least in the case of Diffie-Hellman moduli. A good reference is the Prime and Prejudice paper by Albrecht, Massimo, Paterson and Somorvsky. For these and other reasons, cryptographic implementations are moving towards using the BPSW primality test in place of Miller-Rabin.

Addition: generating $(6n+1)(12n+1)(18n+1)$ where all three brackets are prime can be done by sieving for the suitable $n$. For every small prime $p$, we must have $6n+1\not≡0\pmod p$, $12n+1\not≡0\pmod p$, $18n+1\not≡0\pmod p$, which eliminates $3$ candidates $n$ out of $p$. For example, we must have $n\bmod 5∉{2,3,4}$, $n\bmod 7∉{1,4,5}$.

@Daniel S "at least 75% of MR witnesses will identify a Carmichael number as composite" - i was thinking that for any given base the carmichael number will pass the MR test, if there is any proof or reference to this statement can you please share.

@sg777 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller–Rabin_primality_test#Accuracy or the linked papers.

Actually, if the algorithm is "select a random $n$ and apply the above test; rinse and repeat until successful", this (assuming the conjectures are correct, which seems plausible) is a probabilistic polytime algorithm (Las Vegas - always returns correct result; runs quickly with high probability), not a polytime algorithm.

@sg777: you might be thinking of the Fermat tests, which a Carmichael number will always fool (unless the witness happens not to be relatively prime to the Carmichael number - with a large Chernick number, that happens quite rarely)

@sg77: and, if you are looking to actually implement this, there are a number of optimizations possible that speed up Daniel's test significantly; for one, it is possible to skip the expensive AKS tests entirely (and still have $6n+1, 12n+1, 18n+1$ provably prime).  On the other hand, if all you're interested in is "does there exist a probabilistic polytime algorithm to generate Carmichael numbers", Daniel's answer is fine

@poncho, I'm actually implementing this, i have been trying to generate 2048 Carmichael number for about 4 days on my personal computer, so far I couldn't find a single one. What I'm doing is, generating a random n which is 680 bit number and checking if the $6n+1, 12n+1, 18n+1$ are prime using MR test, if all these three factors are prime then I'm considering it as Carmichael number.  Since its been 4 days and no luck i felt like I can't find this in polynomial time using this approach.

@poncho, my objective of generating Carmichael numbers in polynomial time is to prove a case that one can actually plant a bug in black box RSA key gen H/W modules by intentionally generating weak keys on purpose. I'll try the approach of randomly select $n$ and compute $(6n+1)(12n+1)(18n+1)$ and directly test its primality.

@sg777: have you tried fgrieu's suggestion for testing the three for sieving modulo small primes?  That's actually a pretty good boost (and when you're searching for three primes, you might want to check the small primes up to, say, a million...)

@poncho haven't tried that approach yet, so is it like for any random $n$ do I have to choose all primes upto million and in all cases if $n \notin $ the modulo inverses of corresponding values of primes then consider choosing that n? will this be sufficient or do I need to perform any additional primality tests after this on $n$.


Is there any sort of this kind of insider attack that happened on RSA before

It appears unlikely, as there are better ways (from the attacker's standpoint) to generate trapdoor RSA keys (assuming a black box RSA key generation implementation).
Here is one such:

Pick a $k$ bit random seed $s$ (where $k$ is reasonable size, say, 256 bits)

Use the seed $s$ (and a secret value $t$) to pick a random prime $p$ using a deterministic algorithm

Search for a prime $q$ such that $q = (2s+1)p^{-1} \pmod {2^{k+1}}$


That way, by examining the lower $k+1$ bits of the modulus, the attacker can recover the value of $s$, and then with the secret value $t$, recompute $p$.
And, this observation is not only cheaper to exploit (if you know $t$), it is not useful to anyone who doesn't know $t$.  Hence, this backdoor is useful to the attacker, but not anyone else (and the generated RSA keys are indistinguishable from honestly generated keys).
And, we can do even more - instead of inserting $s$ into the modulus, we can insert $ECCEncrypt(s)$ - if the blackbox implementation has only the public ECC key, then even if the blackbox implementation is revealed, then people (except for the original designer who holds the private ECC key) still cannot use this to factor the keys.
